# Getting a true 95th percentile in DataDog

Tags: datadog

I have an application that publishes a metric to DataDog with multiple tags, and my DataDog agent has a line that looks like

```
histogram_percentiles: 90, 95, 99
```

So my metric (lets call it `ResponseTime`) has a metric in the DataDog viewer for each of those (i.e. `ResponseTime.90perentile`).

However if you look at this metric carefully it appears to be calculating these percentiles on a short range (not sure what) and for each tuple of the tags that exist.

Ideally what I'd like to get is a 95th percentile of the `ResponseTime` metric over all the tags (maybe I filter it down by 1 or 2 and have a couple of different graphs) but over the last week or so.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However if you look at this metric carefully it appears to be
>   calculating these percentiles on a short range (not sure what) and for
>   each tuple of the tags that exist.

The short range that you have noticed is actually the flush interval which defaults to 10 seconds. As per [this](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/205638045-What-is-the-histogram-metric-type-) article on histogram metric by datadog,

> It aggregates the values that are sent during the flush interval
>   (usually defaults to 10 seconds). So if you send 20 values for a
>   metric during the flush interval, it'll give you the aggregation of
>   those values for the flush interval

For your query -

> Ideally what I'd like to get is a 95th percentile of the ResponseTime
>   metric over all the tags (maybe I filter it down by 1 or 2 and have a
>   couple of different graphs) but over the last week or so. Is there an
>   easy way to do this?

as per my reading of the datadog docs, there isn't a way to get this done at the moment. It might be a good idea to check with datadog support regarding this.

More details [here](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/211545826-Why-histogram-stats-are-all-the-same-inaccurate-Characteristics-of-Datadog-histograms-).

Answer (score 3):

Datadog now supports the [distribution metric type](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/distributions/) which aggregates data on the Datadog server-side instead of in flash intervals on the agent side (like histograms). This allows for true p95s, etc. to be calculated over any time period.

After starting to emit a distribution metric, you'll need to enable the percentiles for the metric on the [Metric Summary](https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary) page:

[image: Metric summary percentiles selection]

Then you should be able to see the percentiles on the graphing editor:

[image: Graphing editor with percentiles]

You'll also need to use a new name for the metric if you change it from a histogram to a distribution metric.